# Why does xargs with cp fail for recursion?

Tags: bash, cp, xargs

I am trying to copy files from one directory into a whole collection of other directories, such that the set of files in the source directory will be present in every one of the destination directories.

I am trying to use `cp` with `xargs` to achieve this:

```bsh
# bash on Ubuntu

$ ls -d exercises/*/test/vendor/ | xargs cp ../Unity-2.5.0/src/unity*
```

I understand this command to mean:

- list all the directories that match `exercises/*/test/vendor/`
- for each of those directories listed

  - copy into the directory, the files matching `../Unity-2.5.0/src/unity*`

The directory `../Unity-2.5.0/src/unity*` does not contain any sub-directories, only files
The directories `exercises/*/test/vendor/` do not contain any sub-directories, only files

Testing each of the parts of this command separately acts as intended.

Yet when run, the command outputs `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'exercises/{exercise-name}/test/vendor/'` for every one of the destination directories.

Why? Where is it seeing any directory recursion in what I am asking it to do?

To be clear, I am not asking for alternative methods to achieve my aim - I want to understand why *this* method does not work and how I can adjust *this* method to work (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! Should have read `man xargs`. It's not immediately clear from a basic understanding of `xargs` (that I have), but `xargs` tries to be clever and use multiple arguments at a time.

To prevent this I need to add `-n1` argument to tell `xargs` to use at most 1 argument per iteration.

```bsh
# bash on Ubuntu

$ ls -d exercises/*/test/vendor/ | xargs -n1 cp ../Unity-2.5.0/src/unity*
```

Comment: Another thing to read: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).